# WEKA FP-growth association rules not finding rules

Tags: associations, weka, rules, apriori, market-basket-analysis

For a report I have to find association rules of a data set of transactions. I downloaded this data set:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+retail

Then I deleted some columns, converted to nominal values and normalized and then

I got this: https://ufile.io/gz3do

So I thought I had a data set with transactions on which I could use FP-growth and Apriori but I'm not getting any rules.

It just tells me: No rules found!

Can someone please explain to me if and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one reason could be that your support and/or confidence value are too high. try low ones. e.g. a support and confidence level of 0.001%. another reason could be that your data set just doesn't contain any association rules. try another data set which certainly contains association rules from a set minimum support and confidence value.

Comment: Another set does work, but is the format of my data correct? And will the result still be a correct result if the confidence and support are that low?

Comment: The lower the support and confidence are the more association rules will be generated. An association rule regardless of it's support and confidence values is always correct. It's about the probability that the association of the asscoiation rule applies. Just compare the format of your data set with the data set you tested or check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks you very much!